# Why would select localtimestamp return different timezones on 2 different machines with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, timezone, clock

If I execute on Postgres 9.2

```
show timezone
```

on my machine, it returns the local time zone

```
America/Denver
```

when I run the same postgres command on the guy beside me, it returns

```
US/Eastern
```

Anyone know why the Postgres Server would use two different timezones for 2 different people?

Comment: maybe you're using different settings, so go back to the default: set timezone to default;

Answer (score 0):

The statement `show time zone` shows the time zone of the current client's session. That might or might not be the time zone of the PostgreSQL server.

To see how this works, open two terminal sessions on the same computer, and connect each of them to your database with psql. (I'm connecting to a database named "sandbox". My PostgreSQL server is set to local time. That is, postgresql.conf has the line `timezone = 'localtime'`.)

In the first session, set the time zone to Berkeley, Calif.

```
sandbox=# set time zone 'PST8PDT';
```

(The [default scope](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) for `set` is `session`. This statement is equivalent to `set session time zone 'PST8PDT';`.)

In the second session, set the time zone to UTC.

```
sandbox=# set time zone 'UTC';
```

Neither of these are my local time zone.

Now run `show time zone` in each session. The first one will return 'PST8PDT'; the second will return 'UTC'. The *server's* time zone is still local time.

If I drop one of the connections, and I connect again, I go back to local time.

```
sandbox=# show time zone;
 TimeZone  
-----------
 localtime
```